# How to alternatively check all uitextfields in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm a beginner of swift programming language. I'm looking for alternative way to check all my textfields. What I'm trying to do is. If text field hasn't any value.Change textfield text to red colored textfield name and send alert to user. If user begins typing chance text color back to black.

here is my approach but i don't think it is right way.

```
func alertMessage(title:String, message:String)->Void{

    var alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

func checkAllFields()->Void{



    var allFields=[String:String]()
    var fieldCounter = 0


    allFields = ["Username":userNameField.text,"Name":nameField.text,"Surname":surNameField.text,"Email":emailField.text, "Password":passwordField.text]

    for (field, fieldData) in allFields{

        if fieldData.isEmpty{

            fieldCounter++
        }

    }

    if fieldCounter <= allFields.count{

        var title = "Missing Fields"
        var message = "You need to fill all fields."

        if userNameField.text.isEmpty{

            userNameField.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
            userNameField.text = "Username"

        }

        if nameField.text.isEmpty{

            nameField.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
            nameField.text = "Name"


        }

        if surNameField.text.isEmpty{

            surNameField.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
            surNameField.text = "Surname"

        }

        if emailField.text.isEmpty {

        emailField.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
        emailField.text = "Email"

        }

        if passwordField.text.isEmpty  {

        passwordField.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
        passwordField.text = "Password"

        }

        if retypePasswordField.text.isEmpty{
        retypePasswordField.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
        retypePasswordField.text = "Retype Password"
        }

        alertMessage(title, message: message)



    }



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to simplify the code by getting the UITextView instead its content:

```
func checkAllFields()->Void{

var allFields=[String:UITextView]()
var fieldCounter = 0


allFields = ["Username":userNameField, "Name":nameField, "Surname":surNameField, "Email":emailField, "Password":passwordField]

for (fieldName, fieldTextView) in allFields{

    if fieldTextView.text.isEmpty{
        fieldTextView.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
        fieldTextView.text = fieldName
        fieldCounter++

    }

}

if fieldCounter > 0 {

    var title = "Missing Fields"
    var message = "You need to fill all fields."

    alertMessage(title, message: message)

}
```